# i want to display result of two columns in another table columns is "Activity" how can i execute this query in my sql

Tags: mysql

**i have two column "activity_id & "Project_id" and i want to display result of two columns in another table columns is "Activity" how can i execute this query in my sql**

```
alter table timesheet_table
add constraint timesheet_table
foreign key (Activity,Project) references employee.activity_master(Activity_id,Project_id);
```

\I try this method to execute but it is not run shows error

> Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing
>   index for constraint 'timesheet_tableactivity_master' in the
>   referenced table 'activity_master'    0.000 sec

Comment: What do you mean by "display result of two columns in ahother table columns"? How should that work?

Answer (score -1):

You need to add an Index to the involved columns in each of the tables first.